# master merged to working branch even though I merged the working branch to master

Tags: git, github

- I **pulled** to the latest version of master to local.

  - **merged** the **master** to my **working branch**
  - **Checked** that there are no **conflicts**
  - **merged** the **working branch** back to **master**
  - **pushed** the **master** to the **master** in **remote**

after doing so, I checked the last commit on the master branch on *Github*, and the commit message said:

> Merge branch 'master' into 'working_branch_name'

I stepped into the commit, and **it showed changes that has nothing to do with the changes I made on my working branch**.

Always, I do the same thing, and in the last commit message of the master branch on remote says just:

> Merge branch 'working_branch_name'

and the commit **shows only the changes I have made on my working branch**.

How come that this time it was different?

***P.S***
It has been more than a month since the last time I have pulled the master

Answer (score 1):

If master had changes that were not in your working branch, I would expect the merge from master to working_branch_name to contain changes that has nothing to do with the changes you made. Changes that have been done to master since the last time you pulled will be merged in to your branch.

If there were no new changes in master when merging back, Git would do a fast forward. That would make the merge commit from master to working_branch_name the last commit.

Answer (score 1):

Your history looked like this:

```
         feature
            v
*---*---*---*

*---*---*---*
            ^
          master
```

Then you merged into your feature branch:

```
           feature
              v
*---*---*---*-*
             /
*---*---*---*
            ^
          master
```

Then you merged from feature to master and I suspect you expected this:

```
           feature
              v
*---*---*---*-*
             / \
*---*---*---*---*
                ^
              master
```

However, since you've already merged feature and master, a merge the other direction won't actually do anything, and thus becomes a fast-forward which looks like this:

```
            master
              v
           feature
              v
*---*---*---*-*
             /
*---*---*---*
```

Thus your last commit on the master branch now has a commit message that looks like this:

> Merge branch 'master' into 'feature'

This is to be expected and absolutely normal.

If you absolutely wanted to have the merge commit, empty as it may be, you would have to do this when merging back to master:

```
git merge feature --no-ff
```